# Check to see if field in DB laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a check for the field member is equal to 1.

I've created a helper class and added it in my `app.blade.php`

Here is my code.

Helper Class:

```
function checkMember() {
  $stmt = DB::table('users')->where('member', '=', 1);
  if ($stmt) {
    return True;
  }
  return False;
}
```

app.blade.php

```
@if (checkMember() == True)
  <li><a href="{{ url('/member') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-terminal"></i>Member Panel</a></li>
@endif
```

The error is that it displays the `<li>` even when member == 0 in the DB

Comment: As noted in the documentation, the where method returns a collection.  So its always going to be true in your function.

Comment: Oh, is there a way to change to false?

Answer (score 2):

Your checkMember() method is incomplete - it doesn't launch the query, it only builds it, so it will always be true. Try this:

```
function checkMember() {
  $stmt = DB::table('users')->where('member', 1)->first();

  return $stmt ? true : false;
}
```

I'm also concerned about your query a little bit - this will check if there is any user with 'member' field set to true. So, if you have at least one member - it will return true for all your web users.

Don't you want to do this check against current, logged in user?

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot about that. I want it to check with the currently logged in user.

Comment: Then do something like DB::table('users')->where('member', 1)->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

Comment: @DenisMysenko There is a much simpler method than that: `Auth::user()->member == 1 ? true : false;`.

Comment: @Daedalus well, if we are to make the things as small as possible, why not return (bool) Auth::user()->member? My intention was to change the code as least as possible :)